# Did the Vilna Gaon study Torah on Christmas?

Tags: torah-study, christianity, non-jewish-holidays, vilna-gaon

I'm looking for some information  (sourced) about the Vilna Gaon and Nittelnacht. Did the Vilna Gaon avoid the study of Torah on the night of Nittel (Christmas) as was done by some European communities or was that minhag not followed by the Gaon?

Comment: I've always thought Chassidim really only did Nittle-Nacht. Am I mistaken? For sure it wouldn't seem odd to me if it turned out that the Gra did not abstain from learning Torah on Nittle-Nacht.

Comment: its not mentioned in Maaseh Rav,so chances are he didnt do anything diffrent on kratzmach

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79082/759