# Rav Chaim Volozhiner and Nittelnacht

Tags: christianity, non-jewish-holidays

In discussing the minhagim of Nittelnacht with a few people, I was told that Rav Chaim Volozhin "abolished" Nittelnacht. I don't know why Chaim Volozhiner would have any shaychis to Nittelnacht at all, that he would have to "abolish" it, but does anyone know of any sources that discuss Rav Chaim Volozhiner's dealing with Nittelnacht?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79063/759

Answer (score 2):

he held that someone must be learning torah 24/7 or else world would cease to be. unless he held that it only goes from shkia until chatzos (in which case the 8.5 hour time difference between the u.s. east coast and iran would take care of it), as opposed to chatzos yom of erev christmas to chatzos layla, advocating that everyone should observe nittelnacht would be advocating that there be a time that the world stop learning. however, perhaps he only held that it should be observed in places with a christian population, which many sefardic lands do/did not.

(or it was no longer dangerous to go to the beis in his time/if he abolished not learning entirely it was probably b/c he felt it was a minhag shdus which possibly gives credence to avoda zara)

Comment: Welcome to MY. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. 
Hope to see you around!

Comment: Welcome! This seems more like conjecture about what he may have held. Perhaps a summary of this would make for good comments, but I don't think it makes for the best answer. When you earn 50 rep. You will be able to comment on others'-posts. Hopefully this doesn't discourage you from further contributing to the site in the future.